# How do I transform this code into a list comprehension?

Tags: python-2.7, list, list-comprehension

I have this code in Python2.7 and I wanna (if possible) transform this code into a list comprehension.

```
z=[]
if p==1:
    z.append('a')
    if m==2:
        z.append('b')

print ''.join(z)
```

The problem is it gives me an error (syntax error) when I transformed the code like this:

```
z=['b' if m==2 'a' if p==1]

print ''.join(z)
```

Or

```
z=['a' if p==1 'b' if ==m]

print ''.join(z)
```

Please let me know if this question has a duplicate.
I would appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. I came up with a solution that uses `enumerate` and an inline if statement to tell the difference between the two if statements. Honestly, using a list comp for this will probably obfuscate the code and it'd be better to just stick with the simpler if statements you already have.

```
values = ['a', 'b'] # put the append arguments in here, you can also inline this but I put it apart to make the line shorter
z = [val for idx, val in enumerate(values) if (m==2 and p==1 if idx==1 else p==1)]
```